# Is there a way to dynamically specify the number of threads in a python script?

Tags: python, multithreading

On several occasions, I have a list of tasks that need to be executed via Python.  Typically these tasks take a few seconds, but there are hundreds-of-thousands of tasks and treading significantly improves execution time.  Is there a way to dynamically specify the number of threads a python script should utilize in order to solve a stack of tasks?

I have had success running threads when executed in the body of Python code, but I have never been able to run threads correctly when they are within a function (I assume this is because of scoping).  Below is my approach to dynamically define a list of threads which should be used to execute several tasks.

The problem is that this approach waits for a single thread to complete before continuing through the for loop.

```
import threading
import sys
import time

def null_thread():
    """ used to instanciate threads """
    pass

def instantiate_threads(number_of_threads):
    """ returns a list containing the number of threads specified """
    threads_str = []
    threads = []
    index = 0
    while index < number_of_threads:
        exec("threads_str.append(f't{index}')")
        index += 1
    for t in threads_str:
        t = threading.Thread(target = null_thread())
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    return threads

def sample_task():
    """ dummy task """
    print("task start")
    time.sleep(10)

def main():
    number_of_threads = int(sys.argv[1])
    threads = instantiate_threads(number_of_threads)
    
    # a routine that assigns work to the array of threads
    index = 0
    while index < 100:
        task_assigned = False
        while not task_assigned:
            for thread in threads:
                if not thread.is_alive():
                    thread = threading.Thread(target = sample_task())
                    thread.start()
                    # script seems to wait until thread is complete before moving on...
                    print(f'index: {index}')
                    task_assigned = True
        index += 1
    
    # wait for threads to finish before terminating
    for thread in threads:
        while thread.is_alive():
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You could convert to using concurrent futures ThreadPoolExecutor, where you can set the amount of threads to spawn using `max_workers=amount of threads`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `instantiate_threads(n)`? It creates a list of `n` threads that _do not do anything at all_. And then, after your `main()` has called `instantiate_threads(n)`, it creates _another_ `n` threads to replace all of the threads in the first list. What was the point of creating all of those do-nothing threads?

Comment: Solved!  Thank you @user56700 for the suggestion.  The code is much cleaner now.

Comment: @Solomon Slow - The point of this approach was to create a finite list of mutable threads.  This way they could be iterated upon and updated after execution.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but I wonder if maybe using a [_thread pool_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) would make more sense? You appear to want to limit the number of threads running at any given point in time. The purpose of a thread pool is to improve performance by continually re-using a limited number of threads to perform tasks instead of continually creating and destroying new threads.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

> You could convert to using concurrent futures ThreadPoolExecutor,
> where you can set the amount of threads to spawn using
> max_workers=amount of threads. –  user56700